# How do I make one parameter dependent on another?

Tags: crystal-reports

I need two parameters in my report. I know how to make them, but I need the 2nd one to depend on what the person chose for the first answer. For example, if you choose USA as a country, I need the second one to show only states in the USA.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

while creating a parameter.

1. select option as dynamic.
2. Then start selecting the database fields in parameters, First select country and then states
3. by clicking on the 2nd column you name the parameters.. you can change the name as you wish after clicking `ok` by using rename option.
4. Now place parameters in report of set parameters in record selection formula.
5. When you refresh the report you get parameters with dependency.